# Is it possible to disable the touch panel?

Tags: android, lockscreen

i am developing a app for lock screen.
But i have to show a black screen so that auto timeout can occur so the user can use normal unlock methods.

but the problem is if user touches the screen then auto timeout resets even though i had set the whole screen layout untouchable using this :

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Can anyone tell me how can the screen timeout happen exactly after the set time and the timeout runs as soon as the activity is created and dos not resets when user touches the screen.

Comment: Have you also thought about the hardware keys (Home button, Power button etc...) and what you want to do about them ?

Comment: I want to disable them also.